# WebSocket handshake with Ruby and EM::WebSocket::Server

Tags: javascript, ruby, websocket, em-websocket

I am trying to create a simple WebSocket connection in JavaScript against my Rails app. I get the following:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is missing

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:4000');

socket.onopen = function() {
  var handshake =
    "GET / HTTP/1.1\n" +
    "Host: localhost\n" +
    "Upgrade: websocket\n" +
    "Connection: Upgrade\n" +
    "Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==\n" +
    "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: quote\n" +
    "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\n" +
    "Origin: http://localhost\n";

  socket.send(handshake);
};

socket.onmessage = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
};
```

Ruby:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'em-websocket-server'

module QuoteService
  class WebSocket < EventMachine::WebSocket::Server
    def on_connect
      handshake_response =  "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\n"
      handshake_response << "Upgrade: websocket\n"
      handshake_response << "Connection: Upgrade\n"
      handshake_response << "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=\n"
      handshake_response << "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: quote\n"

      send_message(handshake_response)
    end

    def on_receive(data)
      puts 'RECEIVED: ' + data
    end
  end
end

EventMachine.run do
  print 'Starting WebSocket server...'
  EventMachine.start_server '0.0.0.0', 4000, QuoteService::WebSocket
  puts 'running'
end
```

The handshake headers are per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#WebSocket_protocol_handshake).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. I think that once the connection is open the request and response have already occurred, so sending headers at that point is too late.  In addition, headers have to end with a blank line, which you omitted.
2. According to the demos, you don't even have to set headers in the client or the server--the ruby module automatically takes care of the headers on the server side, and html5 automatically takes care of the headers on the client side.  I think this should work:

   require "em-websocket-server"

   class EchoServer < EM::WebSocket::Server

   def on_connect
   EM::WebSocket::Log.debug "Connected"
   puts "I felt a connection."
   end

   def on_receive msg
   puts "RECEIVED: #{msg}"
   send_message msg
   end

   end

   EM.run do
   myhost = "0.0.0.0"
   myport = 8000
   puts "Starting WebSocket server.  Listening on port #{myport}..."
   EM.start_server myhost, myport, EchoServer
   end

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head><title>Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var myWebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");

  myWebSocket.onopen = function(evt)    { 
    console.log("Connection open. Sending message..."); 
    myWebSocket.send("Hello WebSockets!");       };

  myWebSocket.onmessage = function(evt)    { 
    console.log(evt.data);
    myWebSocket.close();   };

  myWebSocket.onclose = function(evt)    { 
    console.log("Connection closed.");    };

  myWebSocket.onerror = function(err)   {
    alert(err.name + " => " + err.message);   } </script>

</head> <body>   <div>Hello</div> </body> </html>
```

And it does work in Safari 5.1.9 (which is an older browser): I see the expected output on both the server and the client.  However, the code does not work in Firefox 21: I get the error message...

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8000/.
    var myWebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");
```

I notice that in both Firebug and Safari Developer Tools, the server does not send a Sec-WebSocket-Accept header:

```
Response Headers

Connection          Upgrade
Upgrade         WebSocket
WebSocket-Location  ws://localhost:8000/
WebSocket-Origin    null


Request Headers

Accept                  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding         gzip, deflate
Accept-Language         en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control           no-cache
Connection          keep-alive, Upgrade
DNT                 1
Host                    localhost:8000
Origin                  null
Pragma                  no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key   r9xT+ywe533EHF09wxelkg==
Sec-WebSocket-Version   13
Upgrade                 websocket
User-Agent          Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
```

Nothing I tried would make the code work in Firefox 21.0.  To check whether Firefox 21.0 even supports websockets, I went to:

```
http://www.websocket.org/echo.html
```

and it said my browser does support websockets.

3. Is there any reason you have to use the em-websocket-server module? The last modification for that module on github was three years ago.  And whenever you see `require rubygems` in ruby code, that should alert you that the code is old.  I tried the newer em-websocket module, and I was able to successfully transfer data back and forth using websockets on both Firefox 21.0 and Safari 5.1.9:

   require 'em-websocket'

   myhost = "0.0.0.0"
   myport = 8000

   EM.run {
   puts "Listening on port #{myport}..."

   EM::WebSocket.run(:host => myhost, :port => myport, :debug => false) do |ws|

   ```
    ws.onopen do |handshake|
      path = handshake.path
      query_str = handshake.query
      origin = handshake.origin

      puts "WebSocket opened:"
      puts "\t path  \t\t -> #{path}" 
      puts "\t query_str \t -> #{query_str}"
      puts "\t origin \t -> #{origin}"
    end 

    ws.onmessage { |msg|
      ws.send "Pong: #{msg}"
    }
    ws.onclose {
      puts "WebSocket closed"
    }
    ws.onerror { |e|
      puts "Error: #{e.message}"
    }
   ```

   end
   }

Same client side code. Now the response headers include Sec-WebSocket-Accept:

```
Response Headers

Connection          Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept    LyIm6d+kAAqkcTR744tVK9HMepY=
Upgrade                 websocket


Request Headers

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive, Upgrade
DNT 1
Host    localhost:8000
Origin  null
Pragma  no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key   pbK8lFHQAF+arl9tFvHn/Q==
Sec-WebSocket-Version   13
Upgrade websocket
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
```

In your code, I don't think you are setting any headers.  Instead, you are just sending messages back and forth that happen to contain characters that look like headers.  Apparently, your browser requires the Sec-WebSocket-Accept header in the response before it will allow the connection, and when the em-websocket-server module fails to set that header in the response, your browser refuses the connection.

The relevant source code for em-websockets-server looks like this:

```
module EM
  module WebSocket
    module Protocol
      module Version76
      
        # generate protocol 76 compatible response headers
        def response
          response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n"
          response << "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n"
          response << "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
          response << "Sec-WebSocket-Origin: #{origin}\r\n"
          response << "Sec-WebSocket-Location: #{scheme}://#{host}#{path}\r\n"
  
          if protocol
            response << "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: #{protocol}\r\n"
          end

          response << "\r\n"
          response << Digest::MD5.digest(keyset)

          response
        end
```

As you can see, it doesn't set the Sec-WebSocket-Accept header.  That code is in a module called Version76, and searching google for websockets version 76 yields an obsolete protocol(which contains an example of a request and response):

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76

Here is the current websockets protocol(which also contains an example of a request and response):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455

Conclusion: **em-websockets-server is obsolete**.

Comment: Excellent; thank you! It works. One minor correction: EM::WebSocket.run needed to be EM::WebSocket.start. I edited your answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Chad Johnson, Please don't edit my posts.  I find that highly offensive.  When I post code, it's code that I've tested, and it is what I am standing behind.  If the code doesn't work for you, then write your own post to discuss why it doesn't work and/or post other solutions.  By editing my post, you are misrepresenting what I said.  I do thank you for at least notifying me that you edited my post.  The first demo for em::websocket uses the run() method, and I see that the other demos use the start() method.  I checked the docs, and I do not understand the difference between run() and start()

Comment: If run() did not work for you, maybe it would be helpful to post what browser you used and your OS.  I used mac osx 10.6.8 with Safari 5.1.9 and Firefox 21, and run() worked for me.

Comment: ...and ruby 1.9.3p194, em-websocket 0.5.0.

Comment: I get "undefined method `run' for EventMachine::WebSocket:Module (NoMethodError)" with run(). I'm on 10.7.5 with ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]. Safari and Firefox are client side and have nothing to do with Ruby.

Comment: I am also using the latest code (0.5) from https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket. Gemfile line = gem 'em-websocket', :git => 'git://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket.git'