# nitrous.io websockets - Connection and Upgrade headers required

Tags: websocket, nitrousio

I have a Ruby server using `em-websocket` for websockets.

From the browser, I'm using the following code to connect:

```
var ws       = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host);
ws.onopen    = function()  { alert('websocket opened'); };
```

I know this is hitting the server because I see the server produce the following error:

```
EventMachine::WebSocket::HandshakeError - Connection and Upgrade headers required:
```

How can I ensure these headers are being sent by the client? I'm just using the standard browser websocket API.

Not sure if it changes anything that I'm running on Nitrous IO and I am binding the server to "0.0.0.0"

Comment: You can read this answer, it has lots of details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17377996/6627212 ?

Comment: Connection and upgrade headers will be sent by the browser automatically, nothing you have to do that you aren't already doing to make those headers be sent.  You can use the network tab in the Chrome or Firefox browsers to see the actual initial HTTP request being sent that starts a webSocket connection to verify that it has the proper headers (I presume it will have them at that point).  It seems likely that something in your infrastructure (like a proxy) is not passing those headers on through to your server because it is not configured to support webSocket connections.

Comment: @jfriend00 i think you're right because it was working on my local environment. its just broken on nitrous.io.

Comment: Cool yeah thanks for the help folks. I resolved this by switching to [faye-websocket-ruby](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby) and using it with thin.